# first time using angular-ui-router, cannot find view getting a 404

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just migrated a working front end from brackets to Visual studio 2015, after having to re get all of my packages due to the 260 character limit and the deeply nested bower file paths I am getting a 404. I have been though my code three or four times and I just cannot seem to find the problem. Can somebody please take a look at what I have and point me in the right direction. 
 The error message is that it cannot find my file moduleindex.html in its specified location. But I double check the path and that is where it is.

Here is app.js and app.config.js

```
 (function() {
 'use strict';
 angular
  .module('app', ['ui.router']);
 })(); 


 (function() {
angular
    .module('app').config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $stateProvider.state('main', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: '/views/moduleIndex.html'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('register', {
            url: '/register',
            templateUrl: '/views/register.html',
            cotroller: 'register'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('userSettings', {
            url: '/userSettings',
            templateUrl: '/views/userSettings.html',
            cotroller: 'userSettings'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('doctorView', {
            url: '/doctorView',
            templateUrl: '/views/doctorView.html',
            cotroller: 'doctorView'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('injuriesDict', {
            url: '/injuriesDict',
            templateUrl: '/views/injuriesDictionary.html',
            cotroller: 'injuriesDictionary'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('excercisesDict', {
            url: '/excercisesDict',
            templateUrl: '/views/excercisesDictionary.html',
            cotroller: 'injuriesDictionary'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('patientEntry', {
            url: '/patientEntry',
            templateUrl: '/views/patientEntryForm.html',
            cotroller: 'patientEntry'
        });


        $stateProvider.state('patientView', {
            url: '/patientView',
            templateUrl: '/views/patientView.html',
            cotroller: 'patientView'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('therapistView', {
            url: '/therapistView',
            templateUrl: '/views/therapistView.html',
            cotroller: 'therapistView'
        });

        $stateProvider.state('adminView', {
            url: '/adminView',
            templateUrl: '/views/adminView.html',
            cotroller: 'adminView'
        });

    });
 })();
```

Here is index.html

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- bower:css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"    href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/animate.css/animate.css" />
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min-flatly.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
    <![endif]-->
    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <div class="header">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container" ng-cloak>
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#js-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a class="navbar-brand" ng-sref="#/">Physical Therapy Fitness Tracker</a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="js-navbar-collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="main">Module Index</a></li>
                        <li><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="register">Register</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div ui-view></div>
        <div class="alert alert-{{alert.type}} animated main -alert" ng-class="{'flipInY': alert.show, 'flipOutY':!alert.show, 'alert-hidden': !alert.hasBeenShown}"><strong>{{alert.title}}</strong>{{alert.message}}</div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>From JBDesign</p>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
    <script>
        ! function(A, n, g, u, l, a, r) {
            A.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l, A[l] = A[l] || function() {
                    (A[l].q = A[l].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, A[l].l = +new Date, a = n.createElement(g),
                r = n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0], a.src = u, r.parentNode.insertBefore(a, r)
        }(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

        ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');
        ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>

    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/Kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../bower_components/Kendo/js/kendo.angular.min.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.config.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/directives/validateEquals.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/register.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/authtoken.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/patientSearch.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>

</html>
```

I know I am breaking papas put the controller, view, and anything else needed for that module in one place principle. But I am just prototyping something really quick.

Does anybody see where I might be getting my 404, again this was all working fin with no errors in the console coded in brackets. I need to move into visual studio so that I can integrate with Web API. forgive me if it is something dumb, I am still learning Angular.

Thanks in advance, John.

Comment: Just for fun, maybe try putting in the full file path instead of the relative path and see if that works?

Comment: The problem is simply you're specifying the wrong path to the template (maybe try removing the leading '/'). You can change the template path, or configure the web server to server files from that location. We can't really say anything more b/c we don't know the structure of your project nor the web server, nor how it's configured.

Comment: You also seem to have a lot of typos in your route configuration ... instead of `controller` you have `cotroller` :)

Comment: I will try changing my path. I thought I dragged and dropped it there so it was right but maybe I overlooked it. Thank you. As far as a web server goes it's just being run on IIS express from VS right now.

Comment: removing the / worked thanks. I guess I didn't double check that after all.